# How to format a list of strings into a set of command option/argument pairs in a Bash function

Tags: string, windows, bash, function, ls

### What I want to do

I'm running Git Bash on Windows, and I'm attempting to write a wrapper function for `ls` which handles Windows' hidden file flags correctly.

The command `cmd.exe /c "dir /b /a/h"` will output a list of files in a directory which have a hidden flag. Each filename is output on one line, separated by `\r\n` (being Windows). Filenames with spaces are surrounded with single quotes.

```
$ cmd.exe /c "/b /ah"
.gitconfig
desktop.ini
'hidden file.txt'
```

I then want to format this as a list of `--ignore` options for the final `ls` call.

```
--ignore='.gitconfig' --ignore='desktop.ini' --ignore='hidden file.txt'
```

### What I've tried

I'm using a `for` loop, after setting `IFS='\r\n'`, which should allow me to format each filename string with `--ignore='` and `'`.

```
function ls {
    options=""
    IFS="\r\n"
    for filename in $(cmd.exe /c "dir /b /ah")
        do options="${options}--ignore='$filename' "
    done

    echo $options
    # command ls $options "$@"
}
```

However, the string isn't being split, and all instances of  `n` and `r` in the output are being replaced with a space, so the resulting string is garbled.

```
$ ls
--ig o e='.gitco fig
desktop.i i
hidde  file.txt'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collecting options into a single string variable is going to end up badly. Use an array instead.

```
ls () {
    options=()
    local IFS="\r\n"
    while read -r filename; do
        case $filename in \'*\')
            filename=${filename#\'}; filename=${filename%\'};;
        esac
        options+=("--ignore=$filename")
    done < <(cmd.exe /c "dir /b /ah")

    # echo will flatten the arguments, maybe just run git here
    echo "${options[@]}"
}
```

See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for an extended discussion.

Comment: You maybe meant to use `shopt -s lastpipe`. The `while` constructed like this will do changes only in a subshell.

Comment: Oh, good catch; I didn't realize that applied to arrays, too.

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped a lot. However, I found that `IFS=$'\r\n'` was required to split the lines properly, as per [this answer](/a/24628676/3803805).

Answer (score 0):

You're `echo`ing the filenames in `options` without a quote and `echo` is treating them as separate arguments to be echoed:

```
echo "$options"
```

should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used an array, as recommended by @tripleee, but with a simple `for` loop instead of `while read`. Explicit handling of the quotes around multi-word filenames wasn't required.

```
function ls {
    local IFS=$'\r\n'
    options=()
    for filename in $(cmd.exe /c "dir /b /ah 2> null")
        do options+=("--hide=$filename")
    done

    command ls "${options[@]}" "$@"
}
```

The `--hide` option was used instead of `--ignore` to allow `-a` or `--all` to work as expected.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor explains how this, too, will work for trivial file names but fail horribly if a file name contains whitespace or other shell metacharacters. Single quotes in song or movie titles is another all-time favorite with sometimes really odd error symptoms.

Comment: I created a file called ``[]$(){}'`&;=``, which contains all the Bash metacharacters that Windows allows in filenames. The output from my `ls` function was ``'[]$(){}'\''`&;='``. This is the only weird behaviour I've seen so far, where the sequence ``'` `` is represented by ``'\''` ``.

Comment: Try with multiple adjacent spaces (Windows allows those too, right?) or a wildcard expression which matches something other than itself, such as a file named `[a]` in a directory where you also have a file named `a`.

Comment: These work ok as well. Are there any other patterns you think I should try?

Comment: With `IFS=$´\r\n'` I think you should be fine. Maybe try with paired single quotes too, but single quotes were already identified as weird. The constrained rules for file names on Windows obviously help somewhat.